# Adding text before and after input value dynamically without modifying the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm beginning at Front End, i'm usually a Back End dude, i'm trying to do a simple thing but i'm really not use to it, if anyone can enlighten me that would be great

I'm trying to add a "<%" before the value of an input and "%>" after the value, with the second element; the "%>" moving dynamically with the text.

If someone has a solution to explain to me it would be great. :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're new, then keep it simple:  `&lt;%<input type='text'/>%&gt;`

Comment: That's what i tried at the beginning, but i found it ugly, i also modified the value from a Jquery script but, well, it modify the value, i want to keep it visual

Comment: you want this within the value of the input (i.e. within the textbox area where the user types)? Or visually shown at the outside of the textbox? freedomn-m's suggestion is the latter.

Comment: ...But If you want the former...does it have to be shown at all times? What's the reason? Or could you just attach these values to the final input value e.g. when you submit the form or something? It would help to know what the underlying requirement for this feature is.

Comment: That's about PHP component if i understand correctly, i'm replacing a colleague whe he's in holiday but i'm completly not use to it. It's completly visual, the goal is that i don't want people to write "<%COMPONENT%>" in the input field but only "COMPONENT", but keep the <% %> part in the textbox so they're not lost. Sorry for my broken english i'm trying...

I want them inside not outside

Comment: "keep the <% %> part in the textbox so they're not lost" ...again you could just add that to the string at the time when the data is saved. (I assume the data is saved from the textbox at some point, otherwise what purpose does it have?). You could also try and detect if the user already added these tags and then don't add any extra ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements for something like that. Your requirement of "moving dynamically with the text" is not really doable with a regular form input and NO JavaScript as form inputs do not grow horizontally by themselves. To achieve that you could use the `contenteditable` attribute on any HTML element, but then you'll need some JS logic to handle the value when your form is submitted (like copying the text-value of the contenteditable into a hidden input when it's changed)

```css
.form__field {
  display: block;
}

.form__field > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form__input-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.form__input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.form__input:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  outline: none;
}

[data-before]:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
[data-after]:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- regular form input, does not grow! -->
<label class="form__field">
  <span class="form__label">I'm the label</span>
  <div class="form__input-wrap" data-before="<%" data-after="%>">
    <input class="form__input" type="text" value="Some Value" />
  </div>
</label>

<!-- example with contenteditable, does do the "growing" input field part -->
<label class="form__field">
  <span class="form__label">I'm the label</span>
  <div class="form__input-wrap" data-before="<%" data-after="%>">
    <div class="form__input" contenteditable="true">Some Value</div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: This seems fine, i wanna try if i can send that to my form, and if it work, that'll be perfect, thanks :)